# Windows Command Prompt :echo a variable without double quotes

Tags: windows, echo, command-prompt

How can i echo a  variable in Windows Command Prompt without the double quotes?
I want to use a One-Liner in terminal and no batch script.
something like :

```
set myvar="somevalue"
```

and now i want to

```
echo %myvar%
```

and get

somevalue instead of "somevalue".
Is this possible at all?

Comment: If you really just don't want the quotes in the variable, you can quote the entire expression, e.g. `set "myvar=somevalue"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo %myvar:"=% 


echo %myvar:~1,-1%
```

The first way substitutes all occurrences of the string following the `:` with the string following the `=`

The second way selects the substring from "character 1" (batch counts the first character as "character 0") to the first-before-the-end.

see `set /?` from the prompt for documentation. The examples use `path` but can be applied to any ordinary environment variable.